# Function than merges VSC files into one data frame

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, dataframe

I have a folder with over 300 CSV files, each containing a data frame with header.  They are named `001.csv` `002.csv` and so on.  All the files have the same four columns (`Date`, `sulfate`, `nitrate`, and `ID`) but vary in the number of observation.

I want to create a function that will allow the user to select one, all or a range of those files and to merge them into one data frame, keeping ALL the data of the merged files (no need to compare them and find duplicates, etc.)  When I say merge, I mean that the new merged data frame would still have those four columns with the observations from both files.

Here is what I have done so far, where `directory` is the location of the files and `id` specifies the files to load (example: `1` would load file `001.csv`, `274` loads file `274.csv`  and `20:100` loads files `020.csv` through `100.csv`).

```
getfile3 <- function(directory = getwd(), id) {
    # add 0s to ID
    filenames <- sprintf("%03d.csv", id)

    # find requested files
    filedir <- file.path(directory, filenames)

    # determine number of files requested
    numOfFiles <- length(filenames)

    #create empty data frame to store merged files
    dataset <- data.frame()

    if(numOfFiles < 2) {    # if only one file is requested...
        dataset <- read.csv(filedir, header = TRUE)    # use read.csv
    } else {    # else loop over each file requested and merge into "dataset"
        for(i in filenames) {
            dataset <- merge(dataset, filenames[i], all=TRUE)
        }
    }
    dataset
}
```

I works only when loading one file, whichever one.  If I want to load a range, I get an empty data frame.  For example, if I run:

```
newDF <- getfile3("specdata", 1:10)
```

Where `specdata` is the name of the folder where the files are located and `1:10` means I want to load the first 10 files, I get a new data frame (`newDF`) with 0 observations and 3 variables: `V1`, `V2`, `y[FALSE,]` (and `row.names`).
There should be 7,304 observation with the 4 variables from the original files.

The problem is in my `for` loop.

Comment: I don't know how to do the sub-selection but you can load all the files in one go using something like: `newDF<-do.call(rbind,lapply(list.files(path="~/specdata",pattern="*.csv"),read.csv,header=TRUE, sep=","))`

Comment: you're not reading the file in, if numOfFiles !=2. You need to read it and then merge it.

Comment: This is homework and should be marked as such. In fact, I'm doing the same homework now... it's from Coursera's "R programming" class by JHU.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to as below

```
if(numOfFiles < 2) {    # if only one file is requested...
    dataset <- read.csv(filedir, header = TRUE)    # use read.csv
} else {    # else loop over each file requested and merge into "dataset"
        #Use lapply to read in your data
        data.reqd <-lapply(filedir, read.csv, header=T)
        #Merge all the data, using Reduce
        dataset <-Reduce(function(...) merge(...,all=T),data.reqd)
    }
return(dataset)
}
```